# Como ver el query generado por EF en core 3.1

Tags: sql, entity-framework, visual-studio-2019

He intentado varios métodos pero no logro ver el query generado por EF:

```
var CustomerCountries = _mapper.Map<CustomerCountriesDto, CustomerCountries>(customerCountriesDto);                    
var a = _context.Update(CustomerCountries);
                        
var sql = ((System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery)a).ToTraceString();
```

El nombre de espacio Entity no existe

```
_context.Database.Log = s => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s);
```

No contiene una definición para log

```
var sql = a.ToString();
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Muestra:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.EntityEntry`1[ManufacturaMVC.Models.CustomerCountries]

Me podrían decir por favor qué me hace falta o algún método?

Por consola por ejemplo, se puede?

Answer (score 0):

La propiedad `DbContext.Database.Log` es parte de EF6+ y todavía no está incluida en EF Core.
La buena noticia es que se puede lograr algo similar con el mecanismo de logging integrado en EF Core.

Este ejemplo fue probado en una aplicación de consola.

En primer lugar debes declarar una instancia singleton/global de `LoggerFactory`.

```
public static readonly ILoggerFactory loggerFactory = LoggerFactory.Create(
    builder =>
    {
        builder
        .AddFilter((category, level) => 
            category == DbLoggerCategory.Database.Command.Name && 
            level == LogLevel.Information)
        .AddConsole();
    });
```

Luego debes registrar la instancia del LoggerFactory en EF Core, esto lo haces en el método `OnConfiguring` que se sobreescribe (override) en la implementación del DbContext.

Por ejemplo:

```
public class UnTipicoDbContext : DbContext
{
        
    public DbSet ...
    public DbSet ...
    ...
    
    //En este método se registra el LoggerFactory
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
        => options.UseLoggerFactory(loggerFactory) //Esta es la instrucción de interés
                  .Use...
}
```

Con este ejemplo serán mostradas, en la consola, las instrucciones SQL enviadas a la base de datos junto a alguna información adicional.